# Create file with content, where the content has new line

Tags: linux

In linux, **how to create a file** with content whose single line with `\n` (or any line separator) is translated into multi-line.

fileA.txt:

```
trans_fileA::abcd\ndfghc\n091873\nhhjj 
trans_fileB::a11d\n11hc\n73345
```

Code:

```
while read line; do
         file_name=`echo $line | awk -F'::' '{print $1}' `
         file_content=`echo $line | awk -F'::' '{print $2}' `
             echo $file_name
             echo $(eval echo ${file_content}) 
         echo $(eval echo ${file_content}) > fileA.txt
```

The trans_fileA should be:

```
abcd
dfghc
091873
hhjj
```

Comment: `while read line; do f=$(echo "$line" | awk ...)` is an anti-pattern.  Don't do that.  Instead, let `read` split the line for you: `while IFS=: read file_name _ file_content _; do ...`

Comment: It seems like multiple `echo >> $file` would be the easiest way to create a multi-line file.

Comment: Thanks @William. I would change to IFS=::

Comment: Single characters of IFS are used to split words, so providing `:` does not make `::` the separator.  `IFS=:` is effectively the same as `IFS=::`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way (with `bash`):

```
# read input file line by line, without interpreting \n
while read -r line  
do 
    # extract name 
    name=$(echo $line | cut -d: -f 1) 
    # extract data 
    data=$(echo $line | cut -d: -f 3)

    # ask sed to replace \n with linefeed and store result in name
    echo $data | sed 's/\\n/\n/g' > "$name"

# read data from given file
done < fileA.txt
```

---

You can even write a smaller code:

```
while read -r line  
    do echo $line | cut -d: -f 3 | sed 's/\\n/\n/g' > "$(echo $line | cut -d: -f 1) "
done < fileA.txt
```

Comment: echo $line | cut -d: -f 3 | sed 's// /\n/g' > "$(echo $line | cut -d: -f 1) " -- How to change if the delimiter is space...

Comment: If delimiter is space, you can change the `sed` command : `'s/ /\n/g'`